# Switching Manipulate functionality off before saving graphics

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have created 3 charts with `Manipulate`, and I have then placed them in a `Grid` for saving:

```
charts = {{ChartA}, {ChartB}, {ChartC}};
rowlabels = {{"ϵ = 0", SpanFromLeft}, {"ϵ = 0.75", SpanFromLeft}, {"ϵ = 1", SpanFromLeft}};
Grid@Riffle[rowlabels, charts]
```

I would prefer the `Manipulate` functionality to be gone as I save the image, so that I don't need to create static instances of my charts before placing them into the grid.

Can I switch the `Manipulate` functionality off before saving my graphics, including removing the outline border?

I have discovered pressing "+" leads to removing the sliders, but I have not been able to find a way to remove the two borders (see image).

[image]

Comment: use the option `Paneled -> False` in `Manipulate`?

Comment: a more convenient approach is to use [`DynamicSetting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicSetting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`Paneled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Paneled.html)

You can set the value of the option `Paneled` to `False`

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {i, 1, 10}, Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### [`DynamicSetting`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicSetting.html)

A more convenient approach is to use `DynamicSetting`:

```
DynamicSetting @ Manipulate[Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

You can use it two different ways:

(1) You evaluate the line using <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>. Then, if you put the cursor next to the manipulate image and hit <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`Enter`</kbd> current `Manipulate` content is copied in the next cell without panel borders. you can click to the left of that output and give it a name. You can create additional charts in the same way.

(2) You can [EvaluateInPlace](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/EvaluateInPlace.html) to turn the code into a `Manipulate` object. To do this, you highlight the code and hit <kbd>`Control`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>. You can paste the current content in the next cell by using <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>.

#### PasteSnapshot

You can use `Paste Snapshot` from <kbd>`+`</kbd> menu to copy the code that generates the current content in the next cell. You can assign a name  to that expression and evaluate it to get a chart without panel frames.

[image]